# How to validate existance of a file using postman script?

Tags: javascript, postman, file-exists

I am testing a API which in returns response and for authenticated user along with that also download a file in local.
I want to validate that whether the file is getting downloaded.

```
var testFile= new File("/data/file/abc.json");

if(`TestFile`.exists()){
  write('The file exists');
}else{
  write('The file does not exist');
}
```

I am getting error that `ReferenceError: File is not defined`

Comment: What language are you working with?

Comment: I am new to Postman and started just few days back. I was trying javascript functions to do it.